# ¿En que casos se puede utilizar Negación lógica bit a bit, Negación unitaria?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

Estuve leyendo sobre este tema, navegando un rato por google pero nada que hable sobre de en que casos se podría utilizar estos **dos operadores** o que tipo de problemas podría resolver.

Comment: Los operadores bit a bit, se usan primariamente en campos de tipo bandera, donde cada bit representa algo particular. Muy usado en protocolos de comunicacion, compresion y criptografia donde se intenta ahorrar bytes.

Comment: @rnd Excelente Informacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los operadores de bit se usan en situaciones en las que sean necesarias manipular a nivel de bits un Byte.

Algunos operadores son (en Java):

- NOT ( ~ )
- AND ( & )
- OR ( | )
- XOR (^)
- Desplazamientos ( << y >> )
- Rotaciones ( >>> )

Algunos de los usos mas comunes son:

- Lenguajes de bajo nivel
- Funciones como la generación de números pseudoaleatorios
- Programas antiguos donde el se solía empaquetar variables mas pequeñas en Bytes para ahorrar espacio
- Algoritmos complejos de cifrado y compresión
- Programación de protocolos y transmisión de datos empaquetados